# Call tinyMCE windowManager.open with a percentage value for window width

Tags: tinymce

The script below invokes an inline popup window from a tinyMCE editor. I need to convert the width to a percentage value instead of a pixel based value. Any ideas how?

```
(function() {
    // Load plugin specific language pack
    tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('CustomCodes');

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.CustomCodes', {
        /**
         * Initializes the plugin, this will be executed after the plugin has been created.
         * This call is done before the editor instance has finished it's initialization so use the onInit event
         * of the editor instance to intercept that event.
         *
         * @param {tinymce.Editor} ed Editor instance that the plugin is initialized in.
         * @param {string} url Absolute URL to where the plugin is located.
         */
        init : function(ed, url) {
            // Register the command so that it can be invoked by using tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceExample');

            ed.addCommand('mceCustomCodes', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    file : url + '/custom_post.php',
                    width : 1024 + ed.getLang('CustomCodes.delta_width', 0),
                    height : 600 + ed.getLang('CustomCodes.delta_height', 0),
                    inline : 1
                }, {
                    plugin_url : url // Plugin absolute URL
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could messure the inner width of the iframe and assign a pixel value depending on your desired percentage of the width.